# I need help getting Lisp-Stat to load on Mac OS X

Tags: xlispstat

I am running macOS Ventura 13.4 (22F66) on a Mac mini M1 built in 2020 using SBCL 2.2.9 running in the REPL in Terminal.

I tried to load Lisp-Stat with

```
(ql:quickload :lisp-stat)
```

which then tried to load 28 ASDF systems and instal 22 Quicklisp releases. Typical Quicklisp goodness followed but ended with

```
238,213 bytes in 0.08 seconds (3076.55KB/sec)
; Loading "lisp-stat"
..................................
...............operations/generic].
..............-operations/reducing].
...............operations/matrices]
.............y-operations/utilities].
.............y-operations/creating]..
............ay-operations/indexing]...
............ay-operations/displacing].
.........array-operations/transforming]..
.........array-operations/stacking]......
.....................ilities]
[package num-utils.arithmetic]....................
[package num-utils.num=]..........................
[package num-utils.interval]......................
[package num-utils.chebyshev].....................
[package num-utils.polynomial]....................
[package num-utils.elementwise]...................
.................s.extended-real]
[package num-utils.print-matrix]..................
[package num-utils.matrix]........................
[package num-utils.matrix-shorthand]..............
[package num-utils.quadrature]....................
...................rootfinding]
.package num-utils.test-utilities]...............
...................................
Library #P"/Users/sholland/.local/opt/quicklisp/dists/quicklisp/software/cephes.cl-20221106-git/scipy-cephes/libmd.dylib" exists, skipping build
; 
; compilation unit aborted
;   caught 1 fatal ERROR condition
#<CFFI:LOAD-FOREIGN-LIBRARY-ERROR "Unable to load any of the alternatives:~%   ~S" {700A141943}> 
(:LISP-STAT)
*
```

and Lisp-Stat was not available. Any recommendations?